# Is a Cohen allowed to be called up for a Maftir even not on Shabbat?

Tags: kohen-priest, torah-service, maftir

Is it only on Shabbat that a Cohen can be called up for an Aliyah for maftir or even on other days (such as festivals)?

Comment: Hey Stuart, welcome to Mi Yodeya! You might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30736/2091

Answer (score 5):

Maftir is not considered one of the 7 "main" aliyot of the parsha. Technically, the entire parsha has been read and maftir is, usually, a repetition of the last few verses of the the weekly reading. When another Torah is used for maftir, it is a similar idea. The main parsha has been read, and maftor is an extra aliyah. Therefore, a Cohen may be called. This is not just Shabbat - it applies to Yom Tov as well.

The only time a Cohen cannot be called for Maftir is on a fast day afternoon, and Tish'a B'av Shacharit. That's because the 3rd aliyah must be Yisra'el, and that aliyah happens to be maftir as well.

Source - [Talmud Megilah 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=23&format=pdf) near the bottom.

Summarizing: - There is a dispute between Rav Huna & Rav Yirmiya bar Aba as to whether maftir is included in the 1st 7 or not. Tosfot explains that we follow both customs (@DoubleAA's comment is partially correct). On fast days (including Mincha Yom Kippur), maftir is the 3rd aliyah. On Shabbat & Yom Tov, since we are allowed to add extras, we make this a separate aliyah. See the Gemara text as to why there must be a Torah reading before reading from nevi'im (haftarah).

Comment: Actually we hold maftir can count as part of the 7

Comment: @DanF In what way is it only partially correct?

Comment: If there are only Kohanim in the minyan then a Kohen can have maftir even on the fast days :-)

Comment: @GeminiMan http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30682/759